# Getting 'undefined' at component level

Tags: reactjs, axios

I am getting undefined when I run the code below. However, If I console.log the results within the hook, I get all the data

hook (works fine, fetches the data)

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

export const GetOrders = () => {
    const [data, setData] = useState();

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get('/allorders').then(res => {
            setData(res.data);
        });
    }, []);

    console.log(data);

    return { data };
};
```

component (returns undefined when I log the data)

```
import React from 'react';
import { GetOrders } from '../hooks/orders';

export const AllOrders = () => {
    const { data } = GetOrders();

    console.log(data);
    return (
        <ul>
            {data.forEach(order => (
                <li>{order.status}</li>
            ))}
        </ul>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code looks good. Just initialize `data` with `[]` value so it will not break when you will loop over values since `undefined.map()` will fail

```
const [data, setData] = useState([]);
```